# sql update query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to strip off all `_` prefixes in the `name` column, but the result may cause a conflict. So if the result duplicates with existing ones, I want to suffix a `_` to it until there's no duplication.

In the below example case, `_test` should be renamed to `test___`.

```
create table A  
(  
  name  VARCHAR2(20) unique,  
  id int  
);  
insert into a (name, id) values ('_test', 1);  
insert into a (name, id) values ('test', 2);  
insert into a (name, id) values ('test_', 3);  
insert into a (name, id) values ('test__', 4);
```

Comment: Please put in what is the expected output ?

Comment: Why would `_test` be renamed to `test___`? Shouldn't it be renamed to `test`, and `test` be renamed to `test_` and so on?

Comment: What I want is to strip off _ prefix, just because _test be renamed to test will violate unique constraint, so I decide to suffix it with a _, but it still maybe conflict with something and so on. test doesn't have a _ prefix, so it can be ignored.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question. You already have that data, and then try to update those starting with `_`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
merge into A
using (with aa as (select id, trim('_' from name) name from A)
     select rpad(name,
               length(name) - 1 + row_number()
               over(partition by name order by id),
               '_') name2,
          id
     from AA) s
on (s.id = a.id)
when matched then
  update set a.name = s.name2
```

Comment: Better use `TRIM ('_' FROM name)` instead of `REPLACE` to avoid replacing `TE_ST` by `TEST`.

Comment: I think you probably want LTRIM or TRIM(LEADING '_' FROM name), else you're going to strip the trailing underscores as well, which is not what OP asked for.

Comment: @DCookie, actually no, I assumed (and I think correctly - see OP's 4th comment) that it doesn't really matter which "test" keeps the suffix and which one doesn't. So what I try to do here is remove **all** "_" and then re-add them.